# How to convince my boss to buy a coffee machine for the office?

Tags: offices

Need help to come up with some really good arguments for convincing my boss to buy a coffee machine.

We are a small company and there are only 11 people in our office including our boss. We are all been dreaming about that coffee machine for a while now, since we have to spend 2-5$/each everyday on our coffee.

Comment: How expensive is this coffee machine you've been dreaming of?

Comment: Nothing fancy, just Keurig for ~150$ will do

Comment: Are you expecting the company to provide Keurig cups or that people will bring in their own?  Selling an ongoing investment vs a one time investment would be a different pitch.

Comment: Why do you need good arguments? Most bosses would look at $150 to make people stay at the office and be more happy as a ***bargain***.

Comment: Just realized Keurig will need Keurig cups, so mb just a simple coffee maker, with coffee been provided.

Comment: "we have to spend 2-5$/each everyday on our coffee." Who is making you spend that money?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we've decided that these types of questions aren't a good fit for this site: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2134/437

Comment: Just buy a regular coffee pot and a bag of coffee and everyone will save money including your boss.

Comment: Home appliances, and especially electronics with heating elements, like consumer grade water-heaters and coffee-machines are a major source of blown fuses and in the process bringing production machines down. So at a lot of workplaces they're banned. With good reason.

Answer (score 14):

> We are a small company and there are only 11 people in our office including our boss. We are all been dreaming about that coffee machine for a while now, since we have to spend 2-5$/each everyday on our coffee.

**Employee** - "Hey boss, everyone in the office would really appreciate a coffee machine. It would really improve morale if the company would provide one since we all spend $2-5 a day on coffee."

**Boss** - "Yeah? What will it cost? $150? Sounds like our team would pay for it in a week if we all pooled our money and bought one directly instead of going out every day."

**Employee** - "Yeah, you're right! I'll start asking and see if I everyone else wants to chip in a bit and save a ton of money. I'll ask around and get it started."

Ok, it might not be that easy. But many offices do something similar for exactly the reasons you are looking to do so too. Some places will have a community "bank" where people put 25 cents or otherwise have a system to "charge" drinks and donate to replace, etc.

Another strategy would be to propose to your boss something like:

- "Hey boss, we have been talking and would love to get a coffee machine to save money since everyone drinks coffee here. Do you think the company would be willing to purchase the machine if we employees purchase the coffee? Or would the company be willing to do both? The machine we have looked at is $X and would allow us to do Y and Z."

Don't approach this like "a coffee machine would be great!" Give a list of reasons how it will work so your boss knows you (and your team) are serious.

Comment: I was tempted to say - if a company doesn't offer coffee it was grounds for resignation, but then I got my cup of coffee and so you get a +1.